# jquery ui slider live update

Tags: jquery-ui, uislider

I've written a script for a simple jquery ui slider.  There are two sliders (later I'll add more) and when you change their value, it displays below them, and then updates a total.  What I'm having a hard time figuring out, is how to make it so as you're sliding the values are getting updated, instead of getting updated after you've finished.

Thanks for any help!

Fiddle of Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/tMmDy/

HTML

```
<div class="slider_1 slider"></div>  
<p id="slider_1-value"></p>

<div class="slider_2 slider"></div>  
<p id="slider_2-value"></p>
```

CSS

```
.slider {
    width:100px;
    height:5px;
    background:blue;
}
```

JS
    $(".slider").slider({
        animate: "fast",
        max: 25,
        min: 0,
        step: 1,
        value: 10,
        option: {}
    });

```
$(".slider_1").on("slidechange", function (event, ui) {
    total_1 = $(".slider_1").slider("value");
    $("#slider_1-value").html(total_1);
    total_value_update();
});

$(".slider_2").on("slidechange", function (event, ui) {
    total_2 = $(".slider_2").slider("value");
    $("#slider_2-value").html(total_2);
    total_value_update();
});

function total_value_update() {
    total_values = total_1 + total_2;
    $("#total_value").html(total_values);
}
```

Comment: Use the sync'd `slide` event rather than the `slidechange` window events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the slider's [`.slide()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) event and try it like this:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tMmDy/4/)**

```
var total_1, total_2;
$(".slider").slider({
    animate: "fast",
    max: 25,
    min: 0,
    value: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        total_1 = $(".slider_1").slider("value");
        total_2 = $(".slider_2").slider("value");
        $("#slider_1-value").html(total_1);
        $("#slider_2-value").html(total_2);
        total_value_update();
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        total_1 = $(".slider_1").slider("value");
        total_2 = $(".slider_2").slider("value");
        $("#slider_1-value").html(total_1);
        $("#slider_2-value").html(total_2);
        total_value_update();
    }
});

function total_value_update() {
    total_values = total_1 + total_2;
    $("#total_value").html(total_values);
}
```

Comment: hmm, so your last example also worked as well, why is this one better?

Comment: I added the change event which is triggered after the slider stops moving. Without this the total and individual sliders don't show the correct final values.